# Laravel Mix extracting a file in resources folder

Tags: php, laravel

I struggle extracting a single file/path, so it gets placed into the `vendor.js`. The snippet I currently use is:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/frontend.js', 'public/js')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        '../resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js'
    ])
```

And the error I receive is:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                           2:14:34 PM

This relative module was not found:

* ../resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js in multi jquery bootstrap ../resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js
```

The file `constellation.min.js` is located in `resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js`. How can I reference it correctly?

Comment: Try this  `'./resources/...'` of course fill out the rest of the path to your constellation file

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! That solved the issue.

Comment: No problem! should I write an answer for you to accept?

Comment: Yes, sure. I would accept it right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with file structure, `./` is commonly used to signify **"the current directory"**

Since the laravel mix directory is located at the root of the project directory, we will need to work our way out of the root down the proper path:

```
./resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js
```

Thus, we can use in our mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/frontend.js', 'public/js')
.extract([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
    './resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js'
])
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I extracted swiper custom build the same way:

```
.extract([path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources/assets/js/vendor/swiper-bundle.min.js')],'libs/swiper.js')
```

But then I noticed that my entry points importing swiper also contain its code. Thus I just unneccessarily duplicated code. So I came back to extracting libraries from node_modules. Be carefull.